# to combine Javascript HTML PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing this little project. Everything seems working , but I want to make even better.
I have code

-Part1 -takes date from database and converts to JSON

```
<?php
$sth = mysql_query("select Value, Stats from table");
$rows = array();
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Stats', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Value', 'type' => 'number')
);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$temp = array();
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Stats']); 
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Value']); 
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

-Part 2 Draws Google Bar chart and shows it on page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);   
   var options = {
    legend: {position: 'none'},
           bar: {groupWidth: "85%"},
           colors:['#4A9218'],
    hAxis: {viewWindowMode: 'explicit'},
  }                        };                  
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('charts_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div class='data' id="charts_div" style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
```

-My Qyestion

How to convert (combine) Part2 code  to php. I tried  echo around lines, but unsuccesfully

I want to assign Part2 as Php variable $Graph1 and then echo $graph1 on page, because It works better with my other code, so its consistent.

So I would like something like:

```
<?php
Part1
?>
<?php
$graph1=."<script>...</script>"
$graph = "<div class='data'><ul>" . $graph1 . "</ul></div>
echo $graph
?>
```

Comment: Here's a clean way to deliver data to the client [runnable](http://runnable.com/UvJ2ogPxqLw5AAAa/deliver-data-to-client-from-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add it after the `?>` ?

In PHP you can include HTML like this

```
<?php
// My PHP Code
echo "test";
?>
<H1>My Title in HTML</H1>
<script> ... </script>
<?php
echo "test2";
?>
```

You can also include PHP into HTML

```
<script> var a = "<?php echo $somevariable; ?>"</script>
```

You can also wrap your HTML code into a PHP variable care about the `"`. You will need to escape it or us single quote instead:

```
<?php
$myHTML = "<script> window.location=\"mylocation.com\";</script>";
$myHTML = "<script> window.location= 'mylocation.com' ;</script>";
...
echo $myHTML;
?>
```

Comment: Btw, I wouldn't recommend to merge HTML and PHP. There are several technique (like MVC model) in order to separate actions from visual. But this is only my opinion.